# How to pass a variable in an email with Meteor

Tags: javascript, email, meteor, mailgun

Ok i updated my code and now it looks like this

```
import { meteorhacksssr } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:ssr';

SSR.compileTemplate('InviteEmail', Assets.getText('InviteEmail.html'));
var emailData = {
  name: "tom"
};


Meteor.methods({
    addInvite(code) {
          Invites.insert({
            code : code,
            sentTo: 'example@gmail.com',
            accepted: false
        });

         var emailData = {
             code: code
};

    Email.send({
        to: "example@gmail.com",
        from: "example@email.com",
        subject: "Example Email",
        text: SSR.render('InviteEmail', emailData),
});
    }
});
```

Here is my Html template in the server folder with the name InviteEmail.html

```
<template name="InviteEmail">
  <html>
      <body>
          hi {{code}}
      </body>
</html>
</template>
```

But now my app is crashing cmd says : `Error: Unknown asset: InviteEmail.html`
I installed the package and imported it now i have to fix it

Thanks for every help ;)

Comment: @Sean  maybe you can help me

Comment: @Zim maybe you can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the process of converting templates into raw HTML on the server, we need to add a package to our application called `meteorhacks:ssr`
install it using `meteor add meteorhacks:ssr`

for passing any data to replace use handlebars helpers like {{name}}
let email.html is

```
<html><body>hii {{name}}</body></html>
```

and our email code should be like this

```
SSR.compileTemplate('htmlEmail', Assets.getText('email.html'));

var emailData = {
  name: "tom"
};

Email.send({
  to: "to.address@email.com",
  from: "from.address@email.com",
  subject: "Example Email",
  html: SSR.render('htmlEmail', emailData),
});
```

for more info read this https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-the-email-package

and you can also use replace function of javascript for this

Comment: i get the whole time the error "Unknow asset" what can i do ;(

Comment: @Zim maybe you can help me ;(

Comment: @Michael have you seen the link i shared with you? you have to put your InviteEmail.html in /private directory in your project and change "text" in Email.send() to "html". and bring your SSR.compileTemplate('InviteEmail') inside your method addInvite. hope this will help

Comment: wuhu now it works thank you very much ;) yes i saw the link and read it completely helped a lot ;)